# Raspberry 3.0 apt-get fails

Tags: networking, apt

I have a Raspberry 3.0. I am unable to ping yahoo.com, google.com, and a couple of other sites on Raspberry. I am not able to do apt-get update on the Raspberry. Heres the output of the same.

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# apt-get update
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease

Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease

Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.raspberrypi.org'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.raspberrypi.org'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I did add the gateway to my existing connection. I am not able to ping http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org.

I did this further.

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# nano /etc/apt/sources.list

root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# wget  http://archive.raspberrypi.org/raspbian.public.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
--2016-05-27 13:03:48--  http://archive.raspberrypi.org/raspbian.public.key
Resolving archive.raspberrypi.org (archive.raspberrypi.org)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘archive.raspberrypi.org’
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# ^C
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi#
```

Comment: You're not connected to internet - are you trying to use wireless - recommend using direct Ethernet connection to start

Comment: See if `ping 8.8.8.8` works.  If it does, your problem is you do not have a DNS server.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't connect to the internet.